# Handling a POST with an "action" parameter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rails-api

My API is handling a callback from an external source which sends a POST that contains an `action` parameter. This parameter has nothing to do with the rails action, it just happens to be named the same:

```
param1=value1&action=example&param2=value2
```

When this hits rails, rails overrides the parameter to be the name of the action (in this case `create`)... so I get:

```
{ action: 'create', param1: 'value1', params2: 'value2' }
```

How can I access the original `action` parameter in a clean way? Currently I have to parse the `raw_post`:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(request.raw_post)["action"]
```

Which is ugly... anything better?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Rack middleware that intercepts requests that have action in the params and renames them before passing forward.

I believe it would look something like:

```
class ActionParamRenamer
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # you might want to only do this for certain paths
    if env["rack.request.form_hash"] && env["rack.request.form_hash"]["action"]
      env["rack.request.form_hash"]["action_param"] = env["rack.request.form_hash"].delete("action")
    end
    if env["rack.request.form_vars"] && env["rack.request.form_vars"].match(/[\?&]action\=/)
      env["rack.request.form_vars"].gsub!(/([\?&])action\=/, /\1action_param=/)
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

and I guess you would add this to your config/initializers/action_renamer.rb or however that works in Rails nowadays :

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.middleware.use "ActionParamRenamer"
end
```